# SQL ordered filtering from multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a table below, being used by both mysql and sqlite, it is sorted by columns a, b, c in ascending order:

```
   # |  a   |  b   |   c
  --------------------------
   0 |  40  |  55  |  blue
   1 |  60  |  65  |  red
   2 |  60  |  65  |  rose
   3 |  60  |  65  |  yellow
   4 |  80  |  21  |  green
   5 |  85  |  12  |  blue
```

I want to figure out the "next" row after any given row. For example, if I'm looking at row #2:

```
a=60, b=65, c="rose"
```

I want to be able to figure out that row #3 is the next one (I don't have the # ids to use in my case).

My naive approach is this:

```
select * from table where 
    (a >= 60 AND b >= 65 AND c > "rose") OR 
    (a >= 60 AND b > 65) OR 
    (a > 60) 
    ORDER BY a, b, c ASC 
    LIMIT 1
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: what's your dbms?

Comment: @vkp updated the answer, but going to use it in both mysql and sqlite.

Comment: My only useful suggestion is that I think `>=` is redundant; you will match a portion of the next WHERE clause. I think you can replace all the `>=` with `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Exclusive WHERE branches

Only slight change... I think the `>=` can just be `=`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    (a = 60 AND b = 65 AND c > "rose") OR 
    (a = 60 AND b > 65) OR 
    (a > 60) 
ORDER BY a, b, c ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

## IDs Don't Really Help

You can add the "ids" using RANK or ROW_NUMBER (probably RANK because it will group duplicates).

```
// Emulate Rank in MySQL
SELECT @rankInc := @rankInc + 1 AS rank
               a, 
               b, 
               c
FROM table, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
GROUP BY a, b, c
ORDER BY a, b, c;
```

...but I couldn't think of a query that uses this that's better than the one you posted. ***I think your approach is pretty direct and lean.***

```
// Best effort using rank
SELECT nr.a, nr.b, nr.c
FROM rankSubquery r
INNER JOIN rankSubquery nr
ON r.rank + 1 = nr.rank
WHERE r.a = 60 AND r.b = 65 AND r.c = "rose"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filtering, along with `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t 
where (t.a > 60) or
      (t.a = 60 and t.b > 65) or
      (t.a = 60 and t.b = 65 and c = 'rose')
order by a, b, c
limit 1;
```

In MySQL, I think you can also write this as:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.a, t.b, t.c) > (60, 65, 'rose')
order b a, b, c
limit 1;
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same query as given in the question? (save you swapped the >= for = and reordered the clauses).